How to manipulate crossed and nested random effects in nlme model
I've seen some older posts on this but I am really struggling. I am fitting nutrient data and my data is I think to large to dput for posting, I tried to sub sample the data for the purpose of posting a workable example here but the models don't run when I reduce the data. I am using this Weibull function as I determined through drm analyses that it is the best fit to my data. It looks like this:

The data consists of nutrient concentrations in leaves taken over a time series of the growing season at 4 sites over 3 years in 4 trees of different tree species/varieties(different point shapes). When considering random effects and moving the model to nlme to account for them I am having challenges. The years I think should be considered crossed random effects because I used the same sites/trees in all years. Tree should be nested in each site because it was the same 4 trees in each site that were sampled (but different trees in each respective site). Setting up for crossed and nested random factors I know is challenging I have read the half dozen posts out there about this. Starting with this model I get results with random effects for tree nested in site and results are reasonable but I know Year is important:
m1 <- nlme(
Nutrient ~ W1.4_function(Time, b, c, d, e),  # Use predefined W1.4 function
data = data,
fixed = b + c + d + e ~ 1,  # Fixed effects for all parameters
random = b + c + e ~ 1 | Site/Tree,  # Trees nested in sites
start = start_values,  # Use optimized starting values
control = nlmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, opt = "nlm")  
)

I don't want random effects on Weibull parameter d. The AIC drops from 130 to -90 when I structure the random effects like this:
m2 = nlme(
Nutrient ~ W1.4_function(Time, b, c, d, e),  # Use W1.4 function for modeling
data = data,
fixed = b + c + d + e ~ 1,  # Fixed effects for all parameters
random = list(Year = pdIdent(b + c + e ~ 1),  # Year as a crossed random effect
            Site = pdDiag(b + c + e ~ 1),  # 
            Tree = pdDiag(b + c + e ~ 1)),  # Trees nested within Sites
start = start_values,  # Use optimized starting values
control = nlmeControl(msMaxIter = 200, opt = "nlm")  # Increase max iterations

)
Now the groups are:
Number of Groups: 
                    Year           Site %in% Year 
                       3                       12 
    Tree %in% Site %in% Year 
                      32 

Now it seems I have year as a crossed effect but also sites nested in years and trees in sites in year. I didn't intend nesting sites or trees in the year. I know I need to use pdBlocked with pdDiag to somehow get crossed and nested random effects?? Am I better off moving to lme4 methods?

Trying to model crossed random effects with nlme hurts my brain. I would switch to brms: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-017/RJ-2018-017.pdf

I agree with @Roland. It is questionable whether a variable with just three values should be modeled as a random intercept. You can do it, but you are going to get very noisy estimates unless there are very strong year effects. I'd probably model year as a categorical factor in the fixed part of the model.

This was effectively answered in the comments:

Trying to model crossed random effects with nlme hurts my brain. I would switch to brms: journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-017/RJ-2018-017.pdf
– Roland

and

I agree with @Roland. It is questionable whether a variable with just three values should be modeled as a random intercept. You can do it, but you are going to get very noisy estimates unless there are very strong year effects. I'd probably model year as a categorical factor in the fixed part of the model.
– Erik Ruzek

I would not recommend trying to use nlme for crossed random effects. It was designed to accommodate nested random effects, but not crossed random effects. For some background on nested and crossed random effects, see this thread.
While there is a workaround for nlme it is not at all easy to do, as indicated by Roland. Unless you need to model the residual covariance  then you could switch to lme4. If you do need to model the residual covariance, then glmmTMB and mmrm are good alternatives. See the following for a discussion about different residual covariance structures in mixed models:
Beyond AR(1) as a covariance structure for mixed models with repeated measures
And as per Erik's comment, when you have only 3 levels of a grouping variable, it is not recommended to fit random intercepts for it, since you are asking the software to estimate a variance for a variable with only 3 observations. Try some simulations and observe the large range of estimates for the random intercepts. I have had some limited success for cases like this, where I used a Bayesian approach with brms in R, which is also Roland's suggestion:
Advanced Bayesian Multilevel Modeling with the R Package brms
[Link to PDF]
